# run a command in a powershell script as another user

Tags: powershell, credentials

Im a low level IT technician working on a swiss knives like powershell script.
So far, I was able to make it work using only user privileges.
But I want to add a function that when you feed it with an address mac, it tells you if there is already an IP reservation on a given scope of the DHCP.

The command works just fine :

Get-DhcpServerv4Lease -ComputerName xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx -ScopeId xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx | findstr "@mac"

**The issue im facing is that I want to run the script with user privilege, and the command above needs admin privilege.**
So I wrote the command using a Start-Job -credential to feed him admin credential but nothing happens in the foreground.

```
Start-Job -Credential $Credentials -ScriptBlock ${function:dhcp}

function dhcp
{
    $result = Get-DhcpServerv4Lease -ComputerName xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx -ScopeId xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx | findstr "@mac"
    $result | Out-File -FilePath C:\temp\result.txt   
}
```

I thought it was due to user environment/PS session given the fact that I run the script as newbieGuy and the command above as admin_newbieGuy so I tried to use **Out-file** cmdlet so I can get the result of the request on a directory every user have access to.
But the .txt is not even created.

I also tried using **Invoke-command** but I have the WinRM error and I can't modify the way this is setup in my organization.

Im running out of options guys, If you can give me a hint that would be great.

Comment: what is the value of the variable $Credentials ?

Comment: Hello, sorry haven't seen your answer. I use a Get-Credential before that I store in the $Credentials variable